# Use .split() on every x words

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've had this question for a while now, and have been wondering if it'd be possible to use the `.split()` method to split a string every `x` words.
For example, if I were to have a string saying `I am coming for you world!`, I would want to split so every 2 words create an element, resulting in an array: `['I am', 'coming for', 'you world!']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `.match` non-spaces, followed by a space, followed by non-spaces:

```js
console.log(
  'I am coming for you world!'
    .match(/\S+ +\S+/g)
);
```

If you *had* to use `.split`, and `.split` alone, with no further processing, it's barely possible, by looking behind for exactly 1, or 3, or 5 (etc) spaces between the matched space and the beginning of the string (but I wouldn't recommend this approach):

```js
console.log(
  'I am coming for you world!'
    .split(/(?<=^\S+ \S+(?: \S+ +\S+)*) /)
);
```